# Error in Truffle deployment

Tags: truffle

When I run truffle compile, I run into this problem:

```
UnhandledRejections detected
Promise {
  <rejected> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/user/Desktop/AAA/AAA/build/contracts/RedHook.json'
      at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
      at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2155:35)
      at Object.writeArtifact (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/artifactor/dist/utils.js:12:1)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Sharing the code would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some *read/write* permission issue with your folder in which you are working on. Try giving relevant permission to the folder or try changing working directory of your project.